# Spock framework throwing error while mocking a @component

Tags: spring, spring-security, mocking, spock

I am using Spock with Spring and I am getting error while mocking one of my component class.

Please find the below stack trace.
It has nothing more than this and I thus I am not able to proceed.
Versions:

- cglib-nodep : 3.2.0
- cglib : 3.2.0
- spock-core : 1.0-groovy-2.4
- spring-test : 4.1.4.RELEASE

  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory$CglibMockFactory$ConstructorFriendlyEnhancer
  at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory$CglibMockFactory.createMock(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:80)
  at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory.create(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:49)
  at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.JavaMockFactory.create(JavaMockFactory.java:51)
  at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.CompositeMockFactory.create(CompositeMockFactory.java:44)
  at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMock(SpecInternals.java:45)
  at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMockImpl(SpecInternals.java:281)
  at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.MockImpl(SpecInternals.java:99)
  at TermsAndConditionsControllerAPISpec.setup(TermsAndConditionsControllerAPISpec.groovy:19)

Comment: Please update to spock 1.1-groovy-2.4 and use byte-buddy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why this happened but I just removed cglib and it just worked.
So final dependency list was :
cglib-nodep : 3.2.0
spock-core : 1.0-groovy-2.4
spring-test : 4.1.4.RELEASE

I am still not sure why this worked by removing cglib. In case someone has a detailed reason for this please share.